# Avoid keyboard from resizing my MaterialAlertDialogBuilder in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I have a MaterialAlertDialogBuilder with a custom view. Inside my dialog I got 2 TextInputLayout. When I click in the text input layout, the keyboard shows up but it hides almost all my window, making it impossible to read what is inside.
This is what it looks like my dialog:
https://imgur.com/5Objhti
This is what it looks like when the keyboard shows up:
https://imgur.com/a/4FGxrGv

Is there a way to make the keyboard static and just covering the space that it needs without resizing my dialog?

I already tried with **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"** in my activity manifest, but it didn't work

Comment: Try using adjustPan

Comment: It didn't work at all